# iOS: Handling TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR macro

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

My environment:
ObjectiveC using Xcode 6.4 in OS X El Captain (10.11.1). In Xcode, target is set to iOS 8.

TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR always resolves to true in the code below even when I select iPad2 as iOS simulator.

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  // block of code
#endif
```

Shouldn't TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR be set to false when selecting iPad2 as an iOS simulator?

Comment: BTW - why are you using such an outdated version of Xcode?

Comment: I have no choice. Code will not compile if I upgrade to latest Xcode - there's impact to a few libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That macro is true for any simulator build. The macro existed long before the iPad came along. Back when "iOS" was "iPhone OS".

So think of it as "TARGET_IOS_SIMULATOR".

It's used when you have something in your code that should only be compiled when building for a simulated iOS device.

If you need something to run differently between the iPhone simulator and the iPad simulator, you may want something like this:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // This code is only for a simulator
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        // iPhone/iPod touch simulator
    } else {
        // iPad simulator
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 15):

Note that newer macros were introduced in iOS 9 along with tvOS and watchOS, and the TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR macro was deprecated at that time to help avoid confusion.  From TargetConditionals.h:

```
        TARGET_OS_WIN32           - Generated code will run under 32-bit Windows
        TARGET_OS_UNIX            - Generated code will run under some Unix (not OSX) 
        TARGET_OS_MAC             - Generated code will run under Mac OS X variant
           TARGET_OS_IPHONE          - Generated code for firmware, devices, or simulator 
              TARGET_OS_IOS             - Generated code will run under iOS 
              TARGET_OS_TV              - Generated code will run under Apple TV OS
              TARGET_OS_WATCH           - Generated code will run under Apple Watch OS
           TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR      - Generated code will run under a simulator
           TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED       - Generated code for firmware

        TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR   - DEPRECATED: Same as TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
        TARGET_OS_NANO            - DEPRECATED: Same as TARGET_OS_WATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

For any devs using Swift version >= 4.1, it'll be better to use `#if targetEnvironment(simulator)`. Reference: [Target environment platform condition](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0190-target-environment-platform-condition.md)

Code:

```
extension UIDevice {
  
  static var isSimulator: Bool {
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    return true
    #else
    return false
    #endif
  }
  
}
```